# Are single timezone countries affected by security release 5.47.2 event date problem?

Tags: civievent, security

Reading [this note](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/wikis/CiviEvent-v5.47-Timezone-Notice) it's not clear to me whether to go ahead with the 5.47.2 release.  I have several clients using events, but all are in the UK which has a single timezone. I'm assuming the date problem won't affect UK users, but I'd like to check my assumption.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Even for a single timezone site it depends on the timezone of the user running the CiviCRM upgrade and your CMS (if you use Drupal or Wordpress - and if you have regional settings configured in your CMS). On my live test site all my lunch and learns (past present and future) were displayed as 1pm UTC post 5.47 upgrade. That would be early breakfast for me. It was because the Drupal Regional setting was at its default UTC.

Comment: ps I asked Tim who could/should go to 5.47 -> https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/yaw784hf43gg3mzj1aco9uyzxw

Answer (score 1):

reading around the subject I think it depends more on if your UK customers are running events across the world. If they aren't, and the events are purely UK based, then I would not expect to see any issues and I don't think the upgrade is critical for events timezones.

This is just my thoughts from reading around, someone else may have a more background on it.

Comment: If your timezone does not observe daylight saving/summer time, then it might be ok but best to use 5.46 until resolved. A single timezone still has issues if it observes DST.

Comment: I always update the regional settings in my Drupal installs to reflect the UK time zone, so should be OK. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: But for example Europe/London is different than UTC. Europe/London observes DST, whereas UTC does not. You will have a problem with Europe/X if that zone observes DST. Even if you set the regional settings to UTC, if somebody then in 5.47 creates an event with timezone Europe/London, you will have trouble.